# Converging sequence of non bounded variation

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, bounded-variation

I can't think of an example of a real sequence, $(x_n)_n$, which converges, but has no bounded variation.

Just to be clear, $(x_n)_n$ has bounded variation if the sequence $(v_n)_n$, defined by $v_n = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_{i+1}-x_i|$, is bounded.

Can someone help me find an example? Or is it the case that all converging sequences have bounded variation?

Comment: Try $x_k=(-1)^k/k$

Comment: @Kelenner In that case we have $v_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$, so $v_n$ converges, which means $(v_n)_n$ is bounded, so (x_n)_n has bounded variation. :/

Comment: @M vl no: $ |x_{i+1}-x_i|=\frac{2i+1}{i(i+1)}$, a divergent series.

Comment: try $x_n=(-1)^n\cdot\sqrt{\frac1n}$, show it has no bounded variation. You could vary this example, main idea the convergence of the $x_n$ must be very slow, and should approach the limit alternating from both sides.

Comment: @Kelenner Yes thanks! I did the calculation wrong, you're right, $v_n$ is not convergent in the case $x_n = (-1)^n/n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explained the idea in a comment but here is a specific example that might be easier to follow.

Let $x_{2n}=\frac1n$ and $x_{2n+1}=0$, $n\ge1$. Then $x_n\to0$ but $|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|
=\frac1n$ so the variation of this sequence (which I would define as $\sup_{n\ge1} v_n$) is at least as bug as the sum of the harmonic series, which is $\infty$. (That is, if $v_n = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_{i+1}-x_i|$ as in your question, then $v_{2n}$ is at least as big as the $n$-th partial sum of the harmonic series, and we use that the sequence of the partial sums of the harmonic series is unbounded.)

Comment: On a more careful reading, the comment by @Kelenner already gives essentially the same example ... but somehow I misread it the first time (got confused by the second comment, and took me a while to sort it out, and then see I just rediscovered what was posted earlier).